# Async Delegates Callback Pattern leveraging Func

Tags: c#, delegates

All -

I have a sample code for Async Delegates which utilizes callback pattern. I am using the standard delegates and the code below works fine. Wanted to convert it to Func delegates (since its expecting and int and returning an int) but for some reason - seem to get stuck. Can somebody please help.

```
class Program
{
    public delegate int SomeDelegate(int x);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the CallBack Pattern Technique for Asynchronous Delegates in Threading");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        SomeDelegate sd = SquareNumber;
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Before SquareNumber Method invoked.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        IAsyncResult asyncRes = sd.BeginInvoke(10, new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod), null);
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Back in Main after SquareNumber Method invoked. Doing Extra Processing.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Main method processing completed.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int SquareNumber(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Inside SquareNumber  - invoked. Processing......", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return a * a;
    }

    static void CallbackMethod(IAsyncResult asyncRes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Callback Invoked", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        AsyncResult ares = (AsyncResult)asyncRes;
        SomeDelegate delg = (SomeDelegate)ares.AsyncDelegate;
        int res = delg.EndInvoke(asyncRes);
        Console.WriteLine("[{1}] Result = {0}", res, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You've posted the code that *does* work, but not the code that *doesn't* work - which makes it a lot harder to help you fix the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Jon - I am learning more about the generic Func and Action delegates and wanted to use it in the above context. Cant seem to get past the first line which declares the Func Delegates

Comment: So post the code that's giving you problems. We haven't seen what you've tried, so we can't see what's wrong.

Comment: If you mean using a `Func` instead of a `Delegate` then just change `SomeDelegate sd = SquareNumber;` to `Func<int,int> sd = SquareNumber;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
    {
        //public delegate int SomeDelegate(int x);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the CallBack Pattern Technique for Asynchronous Delegates in Threading");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Func<int,int> sd = SquareNumber;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Before SquareNumber Method invoked.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            IAsyncResult asyncRes = sd.BeginInvoke(10, new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod), null);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Back in Main after SquareNumber Method invoked. Doing Extra Processing.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Main method processing completed.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int SquareNumber(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Inside SquareNumber  - invoked. Processing......", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return a * a;
        }

        static void CallbackMethod(IAsyncResult asyncRes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Callback Invoked", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            AsyncResult ares = (AsyncResult)asyncRes;
            Func<int,int> delg = (Func<int,int>)ares.AsyncDelegate;
            int res = delg.EndInvoke(asyncRes);
            Console.WriteLine("[{1}] Result = {0}", res, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks - just a bummer. I wasnt getting the second part which is so easy. Thanks everybody for the help